# Visual Studio can't find class after adding reference and 'using' statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, reference

I'm trying to use [this class for BsonMediaTypeFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.bsonmediatypeformatter(v=vs.118).aspx). I've added `using System.Net.Http.Formatting` to my file and added a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting in my References but Visual Studio still throws an error saying the type or namespace could not be found.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. The System.Net.Http.Formatting Version is 4.0.0.0 while the File Versoin is 4.0.21112.0. My project's target framework is .NET 4.5.  Does anyone know why Visual Studio is unable to find BsonMediaTypeFormatter? Note, this isn't a Web Api project - this is just a simple project containing some unit tests - i.e. I don't have a project.json with nuget packages or anything like that.

Comment: " Does anyone know why Visual Studio is unable to find BsonMediaTypeFormatting?" Well, the class is `BsonMediaTypeFormatter`. Are you spelling it correctly?

Comment: @itsme86 - My fault - that's a typo - i'm using BsonMediaTypeFormatter in my code. I'll update the post.

Comment: I can confirm this error.  I cannot find the class in that assembly or namespace.  I might not have the latest patches to VS 2013, though.  My version is 12.0.31101.00